# Identityserver3 Update Permissions

Tags: identityserver3

I wondering if i could update the current user claims w/o the user having to authenticate again.

In my case the user will log into the application and will receive a set of claims. Later he will be able to change the customer his working with. Once that is done he need to receive a new set of claims.

Does any one know if that can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean claims, not user permissions.

Comment: yes, the user claims. Any idea if its possible?

Answer (score 2):

You almost answered your own question - a token is not a good place to store permissions, because the only way to update the token content is to get a new token.

Tokens are good from transmitting immutable identity data. Everything else belongs into the realm of application or business logic design.

Comment: Alright, after some testing and research i found that what we need is to generate a new token. The idea is that one user can not be authenticated in more then one customer at the same time. so basically we need to revoke the old one anyway. Is there a way to get a new token using the current one, passing along it and also the new customer?